# Why is this not an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My api returns a string.
In JavaScript I would expect to have an array to work with, but it's not and I don't understand why.

```
var array_var = this.response;
console.log(array_var);
console.log(Array.isArray(array_var));
console.log(array_var[0]);
```

This is the response:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "filename": "Den f\u00f8rste fil hedder noget.",
>         "file": "my_string1.decode('utf-8')"
>     },
>     {
>         "filename": "Den anden fil hedder noget andet.",
>         "file": "my_string2.decode('utf-8')"
>     }
> ]
> false
> [
> ```

Comment: If it is a string, don’t you need to run `JSON.parse()` first?

Comment: It _is_ a string, as evidenced by the output `[` for `array_var[0]`.

Comment: Instead of `var array_var = this.response;` try `var array_var = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`.

Comment: Are you using a `fetch` or another method? As @Terry mentioned these things can be sorted when fetching/retrieving the data have a look here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Thanks. But it's not json, it's an array of json's. I would expect to use json.parse(array_var[0])
Please leave an answer, terry, I think you were first to answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as _"an array of json's"_. JSON is a serialized string format for representing JavaScript objects. I suggest you have a good read of this documentation ~ https://www.json.org/. Also, this question is already closed. Please see the linked duplicate